# Visio Stencil for iOS design comps?

Tags: ios, templates, visio, stencils

Has anyone created a Visio template, or just a stencil, for creating iOS design comps?

I know there are tools that allow you to do design comps, but I'm really after a Visio stencil, or stencil template combination, for my particular needs.

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/ is a very popular design template for Photoshop but I'm not a Photoshop guy.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not tied to Visio I would HIGHLY recommend OmniGraffle (http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) instead. It's a great tool with a huge selection of free stencils - including ones targetted to iPhone/iPad screen design.

Comment: Perception, thanks for that advice. I have used OmniGraffle, and it's a beautifully designed application, but Visio is the one remaining piece of software I haven't found a replacement for. It's near and dear to my heart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good set over available over here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/about/stencils/

Comment: Hey, thanks John, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert screenshots or any set to Visio stencil using [this utility](http://dmitry-ivanov.tumblr.com/post/9287357067/png2vss-3-0).

Comment: Please disclose your involvement with this product

Comment: I'm developer of this utility. It's freeware, I've moved it: http://wp.me/P1OeH8-4.